# Currency exchange in database

Tags: sql, database-design, currency-exchange-rates

I am designing a relational database that includes currency exchange rates. My first intuition was to have a currency table that lists all the currencies and holding as attributes the exchange rate for every other currency.

Ex:
Currency Table

- id INT
- base_currency_code VARCHAR
- date DATE
- USD DECIMAL
- GBP DECIMAL
- EUR DECIMAL

I've done a search online on how currency exchange tables are implemented in databases, and everywhere I've looked instead has a table currency_exchange with columns base_currency, non_base_currency (to currency), rate, and date.

Since I can't find an implementation similar to mine and since one post I read said the other implementation is how it's done at the financial company he works at, I assume that the other is superior to mine!

I just don't understand why. Could someone please explain why the other is better?

Comment: Your table is not normalized. What happens if you want to add a new currency? Add another column? No, a table structure should be fixed and not evolve with the data.

Comment: @juergend -- which normal form does this table violate?

Comment: @StevenAnderson first normal form, as pointed out if you need to support new currency you need to add new column. Anything that require you to change table structure is a bad design.

Answer (score 7):

You want tables like something this:

```
create table Currencies (
    CurrencyId int primary key,
    ISO_Code varchar(3),
    Name varchar(255)
);

create table CurrencyExchangerate (
    CurrencyExchangerateId int primary key,
    FromCurrencyId int not null references Currencies(CurrencyId),
    ToCurrencyId int not null references Currencies(CurrencyId),
    RateDate date not null,
    ExchangeRate decimal(20, 10),
    constraint unq_currencyexchangerate_3 unique (FromCurrencyId, ToCurrencyId, RateDate)
);
```